# Run Java application in NGINX

Tags: java, nginx

How can I deploy my Java web application created in Netbeans in NGINX. I already tried [this](https://www.mkyong.com/nginx/nginx-apache-tomcat-configuration-example/) link for configuring my application.

Comment: NGINX is just proxy and you should deploy our web application war to Tomcat (or similar).

Comment: You can't "run a Java application on NGINX". You use Tomcat or Glassfish or something similar. The reverse proxy configuration described in the article is using NGINX as a proxy, and the application is deployed in Tomcat.

Comment: "nginx is just proxy": the nginx people have a different opinion. https://nginx.org/en/

Answer (score 0):

Please configure your nginx proxy setting.

```
location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; #or use http://127.0.0.1:8080
           root /etc/tomcat7/webapps/apple; # path of you application.          
           index  index.html;
           proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
           proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
       }
```

Now check one more thing your server are access your port
please hit `netstat -ntpl` and check your 8080 port and 80 port are one and access but all IP.

Comment: Can we use ngnix for communication between 2 mahines.like any tcp,udp protocol..I want to communicate between 2 machines.But without using tcp/ip or udp protocol.